# Where are the RSS feeds or JSON blobs for new replies?

Tags: discussion

I've wasted a lot of time now, combing through the HTML of the Stack Overflow questions, finding no way to track when there's a new reply. Do they expect me to sit and reload webpages manually like a caveman on a site that's all about coding? That's irony if I ever saw it...

There must be some sort of JSON blob with a nice { answers: 0, comments: 2 } or something? And an RSS feed?

Comment: There are websockets for you to listen to

Comment: There's definetely a touch of irony involved here, but not where you think ;)

Comment: ivarni: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Atom feed at `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/12345` (substitute the question number), linked as "question feed" below the list of related questions.  Perhaps that could be useful for what you're trying to do?

Comment: Well, https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/384527 says "Page not found"?

Comment: Perhaps because that's a deleted question? https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/383680 seems to work

Comment: Hmm. That's strange. I literally used the URL in the address bar after reloading this page. But yeah. That one seems to work...

Comment: Also, both this method (the Atom feed) and my own little "regexp hack" ignore those "comments", which often ask for a clarification or give some other useful hint. Not sure what to do about that.

Comment: Oh right, the feed for _this_ question is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/384527 (adding `meta`; see the link in the right sidebar)